# Why is tethering my Win7 laptop and Bluetooth phone inconsistent?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, tethering

When I want to tether my Bluetooth phone (Motorola Droid X) to my Windows 7 laptop and use it as a modem, I go to "Devices and Printers," then right-click on the "Droid X" icon. (Of course, both devices are running Bluetooth, are paired, etc.)

About half the time, I get "Connect as > Access Point," which is great.  It works wonderfully.

But the other half the time, I get a different menu, with "Modem Settings" and "Dial-up Networking >" etc. on it.  There is no option to connect (tether). If I refresh, or go back later, sometimes I get the correct menu and can connect (however, sometimes I don't).

There seems to be no rhyme or reason to this.  Does anyone know why this is, and how to consistently make my phone more "connectable"?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps..
1. right click on bluetooth icon {it appears on right side tray on desktop next to audio and battery plgins}.
2. select show bluetooth devices .
3. now right click on your device
there you go.